# How do I list all files revisions, changelist number & developer's ID within a directory?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to get a list of all revisions on all files within a directory with this information:

- The version number
- Changelist number
- Developer's id.

I tried using P4 files: p4 files -a *.* > output.txt, but this command has no options to give me the developer's id & changelist number.

Comment: Can you clarify what your meaning of "version number" as opposed to the changelist number is? Is that the file-revision? Also, do you need that information for the "head" action (i.e. latest change) or for the complete history of each file?

Comment: I need the file version number like you had in your reply, but I also need the file name as well included. I want to build a map of the most changed files in a large repository, and who is changing them.

Answer (score 4):

My request for clarification notwithstanding, as I understand your question I think you want to use `p4 filelog`:

```
p4 -c <client-name> filelog ... > output.txt
```

This will produce lines like:

```
//path/to/depot/file
... #15 change 384363 edit on 2011/04/06 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #14 change 381364 edit on 2011/03/21 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #13 change 375094 edit on 2011/02/16 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #12 change 374246 edit on 2011/02/11 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #11 change 374042 edit on 2011/02/11 by henrik.wist@c-henrik.wist-client (text) 'comment
... #10 change 373886 edit on 2011/02/10 by henrik.wist@c-henrik.wist-client (text) 'comment'
... #9 change 373567 edit on 2011/02/09 by max.ritter@c-max.ritter-all (text) 'comment'
... #8 change 373553 edit on 2011/02/09 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #7 change 373350 edit on 2011/02/09 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #6 change 370568 edit on 2011/01/25 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #5 change 368223 edit on 2011/01/14 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #4 change 365805 edit on 2010/12/21 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #3 change 364494 edit on 2010/12/14 by henrik.wist@c-henrik.wist-client (text) 'comment'
... #2 change 362107 edit on 2010/12/02 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
... #1 change 359972 add on 2010/11/23 by user.name@c-user.name-client (text) 'comment'
```

for each file. If you only need the latest change, use

```
`p4 -c <client-name> filelog -m 1 ... > output.txt
```

Comment: Almost, but I also need to do this at directory level, and get the file name and version # as well. I don't want to iterate through the files and do it file by file.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you mean by "at directory level". As far as I can tell, all the information is there, you might just have to use some shell-fu (or ruby-fu or whatever your preferred language is) to join the lines and massage the output.

Comment: @ssm If you want to run the command against a directory, you can use a file pattern like `//depot/dir/*`, which matches all files in a directory, but doesn't recurse into subdirectories, or `//depot/dir/...`, which does include the subdirectories.

Also, you can always add `-Ztag` before the command you want to execute to display the results with tags, which might make it easier to parse.

As jhwist said, all the information you need is present in the results of the filelog command, you just need to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Perforce console near me, but what about

```
p4 changes ...
```

for the current directory on down, 
or

```
p4 changes dir_name/...
```

for a general directory.
I believe it has the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command that will give you filename, revision and user.  Unfortunately you can only get 2 out of 3.  I think your best bet is to write a script that uses `p4 fstat` and then does a `p4 describe` on the changelist numbers to get the user names.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [P4Report](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.082/manuals/p4report/index.html) to construct this kind of compound query. With a fairly simple bit of SQL, you can extract the most volatile files, and you could combine with a query that shows the most active users. I think one of standard reports it installs is for volatile files. But its not hard to work it out for yourself anyway.

The link above is to the documentation - the sample queries in that show how easy it is to use. It's free.