# Is it possible to list files in a folder sorted by last check-in time in perforce?

Tags: clearcase, perforce

I recently moved from ClearCase to Perforce. In CC, I used to sort the list of files in the ClearCase explorer by the last check-in time. Is there any way I can do a similar thing with Perforce ? Ideally, in P4V ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - in P4V, select the directory where you want to list files, then from the View Menu click "Sort by date modified".

Note that you will need to do this in the Depot tab if you want to sort by last check-in time.  If you do it from the Workspace tab which shows your local files, it will include the modification times for any files that you changed locally.

Comment: Problem solved ! Many thanks ! Would you by any chance know if it's possible to display the last modification time side by side with the file names in P4V somehow ? Thanks again. :)

Comment: I don't think you can customize the values that are displayed in P4V, and it's not that easy to list files with their change dates from the command line either.  This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581655/how-do-i-list-all-files-revisions-changelist-number-developers-id-within-a-d